# How to call this method from web service in my test class

Tags: unit-test, salesforce1-app, webservices, code

I am not able to call this method in my test class:

```
WebServiceCallout.invoke(

          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
          'https://www.imed.com.ar/Producto',
          'https://www.imed.com.ar/',
          'Producto',
          'https://www.imed.com.ar/',
          'ProductoResponse',
          'wwwImedComAr.ProductoResponse_element'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement mock interface in you test class, something like:

```
@IsTest
global class Mocker implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
        Object stub, Object request, Map<String, Object> response,
        List<String> endpoint) {

          //you should set here your response **res**
          response.put('response_x', res);

          return;
    }
}
```

After that, set in your test method:

```
Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new Mocker());
```